# Write lines up to matched string in python

Tags: python, regex

I’ve the input file as :

**Input file:**

```
HEAD    xxxxxxx xxxx
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;              
..................
;;;;;;;;;;;;;
..............                                                                    

MODEL        1 

ENDMDL      
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;              
..................
;;;;;;;;;;;;;

MODEL        2

ENDMDL  

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;              
..................
;;;;;;;;;;;;;
..............

MODEL        3

ENDMDL
```

Would like to match string “MODEL      2” and print only above lines
**Desired output:**

```
HEAD    xxxxxxx xxxx
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;              
..................
;;;;;;;;;;;;;
..............                                                                    

MODEL        1 

ENDMDL
```

Also I would prefer to read a file and write it in same file.

Comment: Please check how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hope you understand this question!

Comment: I am glad you've found the solution! The reason your question got a negative rating is that you didn't show your own effort for solving when posting a question. You may have a look at some discussions on this topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372166/we-are-not-a-code-writing-service-comments-are-they-the-good-the-bad-or-the-ug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself this one does what i want.

```
def transp(inputt):
    with open(inputt,'r+') as f:
        f.write(f.read().split("ENDMDL")[0])
```